# How to write unit tests for events in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, backbone.js

I begin my adventure with write unit tests so please be indulgence. In my app I am using jQuery, backbone.js and underscore.js and for tests mocha.js and chai.js. I have problem because I have no idea how to test events using this tools. Fox example I have function which changes value of input. It call after change checkbox value.

**test.html file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Backbone.js Tests</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/lib/mocha.css" />
    <script src="js/lib/mocha.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/chai.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="js/lib/sinon.js"></script> -->
    <script>
        // Setup
        var expect = chai.expect;
        mocha.setup('bdd');

        // Run tests on window load event.
        window.onload = function () {
            (window.mochaPhantomJS || mocha).run();
        };
    </script>

    <!-- App code -->
    <script src="../public/static/js/libs/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../public/static/js/libs/js.cookie-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../public/static/js/libs/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../public/static/js/libs/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="../public/static/js/libs/backbone-min.js"></script>
    <script src="../public/static/js/libs/backbone-relational.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../public/static/js/libs/backbone-super.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../public/static/js/libs/handlebars-v4.0.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../public/static/js/application.js"></script>
    <script src="../public/static/js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="../public/static/js/views/register.js"></script>
    <script src="../public/static/js/views/modals/sign-in-modal.js"></script>
    <script src="../public/static/js/views/modals/sign-up-modal.js"></script>
    <script src="../public/static/js/helpers/forms.js"></script>
    <script src="../public/static/js/helpers/alerts.js"></script>
    <script src="../public/static/js/helpers/inpage-alerts.js"></script>
    <script src="../public/static/js/collections.js"></script>
    <script src="../public/static/js/models.js"></script>
    <script src="../public/static/js/kodilla.lib.js"></script>
    <script src="../public/static/js/views/knowledge-base.js"></script>
    <script src="../public/static/js/libs/tether.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Tests -->
    <script src="js/spec/register.spec.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="mocha"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**register.js file:**

```
App.Views.Register = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click input[name="terms"]' : 'changeTermsConfirmation',
        'click [type=submit]': 'onSubmitForm'
    },
    initialize: function(options) {
        this.$termsConfirmedAtHidden = this.$('input[name="terms_confirmed_at"]');
    },
    changeTermsConfirmation: function(e) {
        if ($(e.currentTarget).is(":checked")) {
            this.$termsConfirmedAtHidden.val(Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000));
        } else {
            this.$termsConfirmedAtHidden.val('');
        }
    },
    onSubmitForm: function() {
        if (!this.$el.find('input[name="terms"]').is(':checked')) {
            analytics.track('auth_register_not_checked_terms');
        }
    }
});
```

**register.spec.js file:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    describe('Register Form', function() {

        App.registerView = new App.Views.Register();

        describe('initialize() function', function() {
            it('Should initialize this.$termsConfirmedAtHidden variable by HTML object', function () {
                expect(App.registerView.$termsConfirmedAtHidden).to.be.a('object');
            });
        });

        describe('changeTermsConfirmation() function', function() {
            it('Should set value of $termsConfirmedAtHidden element', function () {
                //how to test this function
            });
        });

    });

});
```

My question is how to write sensible unit test for "changeTermsConfirmation()" function. I'll be thankful for others notes, usage tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I can help you out with a few bits of info which might get you started.

Mocha/Chai is modular, so first you need to include a mocking/spying library into your project. The default choice for most people seems to be [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/) (along with [Sinon-Chai](https://github.com/domenic/sinon-chai)).

Then you can examine and unit test your event handler:

- Create a view instance for your test.
- Set up a spy on the view method you want to test (`changeTermsConfirmation` in your case)
- Trigger the event by calling `trigger` on your view instance
- Your expectation can check how often your method has been called, and with which arguments, and what its return value has been.

If you don't care about any of that and just want to test view state changes, you don't need a spy (and you don't need to include a library like Sinon). Just create a view instance, call `trigger` and examine the result.

Comment: Thank you for response! Can you tell me more about create a view of instance? You mean I should create separeted html markup? In this case is any way to call all tests from one page or from terminal?

Comment: You can use the HTML document you have. Grab the `body`, append a `div`, create your view within the `div`, clean up the `div`. If you run your tests in a browser, the `body` belongs to the test (result) page  - there is no problem in using that. If you run the tests from the command line, you can use a (headless) browser like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/), and then the `body` belongs to the default document of that browser.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. I know this will works but is it good practice (I mean append some `div` to body in current html page)? Sorry for maybe stupid question but I am really beginner it this subject ;)

Comment: It's fine unless your test is not properly encapsulated for some reason. I have run tests (not Backbone-related) where the document size or the presence of scroll bar mattered - the canvas has to be clean then. Alternatively, you can create a child window or an iframe, but then you have to deal with other issues. For instance, most browsers block child (ie, popup) windows, so you have to change the browser settings before your tests work - not so great.